# Spring Cloud Eureka + Zuul Api Gateway on Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I currently have 2 applications being discovered on my Eureka discovery server. The first application is my Zuul api-gateway and the second is a basic service. My Zuul api-gateway is intended to redirect clients to my basic service and others in the future. Currently my Zuul api-gateway has these defined in it's application.properties.

```
zuul.routes.basic-spotify.service-id=basic-spotify
zuul.routes.basic-spotify.path=/basic-spotify/**
```

When I deploy these services to heroku and attempt to hit the /basic-spotify via the api-gateway, I end up getting a 500 timeout error. Originally, I had used zuul.routes.basic-spotify.path.url which requires the actual url to my heroku application. This way worked perfectly but I felt like it defeated the purpose of having eureka since it was a full url rather than a name provided by Eureka. I replaced it with the service-id which was the name of the service in Eureka. I am not using hystrix or ribbon so the main solutions I've looked at for this problem don't work for my case.